Drawing Virtual Content Relative to AprilTag Corners in MATLAB/Python
I'm facing a challenge with a project involving an image containing an AprilTag (or any other fiducial marker).  My goal is to draw a point or other virtual content in this image at a specified distance from one of the corners of the AprilTag.
I'm working in MATLAB (but may shift to Python if it's hard to do in MATLAB) and using the following to obtain the corners and pose of the Tag.
%estimate the pose of the AprilTag
[~, corners, tagPose] = readAprilTag(I, tagFamily, intrinsics, tagSize);

From my understanding, the pose of the tag gives me the extrinsic parameters that represent the translation and rotation of the tag's coordinate system with respect to the camera coordinate system.
With the following I am able to use the pose to create a virtual cube centered on the tag. This is done by converting the world points representing the cube size in mm to 2D image points (in pixels).
    % Define a virtual content (Cube)
[cubeWidth, cubeHeight, cubeDepth] = deal(tagSize);

vertices = [ cubeWidth/2 -cubeHeight/2; 
             cubeWidth/2  cubeHeight/2;
            -cubeWidth/2  cubeHeight/2;
            -cubeWidth/2 -cubeHeight/2 ];

cuboidVertices = [vertices zeros(4,1);
                  vertices (cubeDepth)*ones(4,1)];

% Use world2img to project the virtual cuboid vertices into the image coordinate system. 
projectedVertices = world2img(cuboidVertices, tagPose, intrinsics)

Is it possible to do something similar with respect to another point in my picture? For instance, if I wished to move the cube 20 mm (in the real world) left of one corner of the tag, could I convert this to a shift in pixels (image points)?
I attempted to use the approach vertices = vertices - offset (with the offset in mm) to translate the virtual content, but it doesn't seem to move it the correct amount.
Thanks for any help!
